# How to find the intersection point of on line?

Tags: geometry

Let's say a line is passing through two points p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2). There is a 2nd line which is passing through the third point p3(x3,y3) with an angle of $\theta$, Assuming that this line will intersect the first line in between p1 and p2. What is the intersection point p4(x4,y4)?

Comment: So what is that angle $\theta$? Is it the angle between the two lines? But it sounds like it's somehow related to the point $p_3$.

Comment: Hi, Matti P , $theta$ is the angle of 2nd line with respect to x-axis.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the line from $p_1$ to $p_2$ be
$$
L_1 = \{ p_1 + (p_2 -p_2 )s, s \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
The second line can be written as the set of points
$$
L_2 = \{ p_3 + t(\cos{\theta}, \sin{\theta}), t \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
Now we simply need to find the intersecting points and solve for $t$. Taking $L_1 = L_2$ and extracting the individual components, we get two equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 + (x_2-x_1)s &=& x_3 + t\cos{\theta} \\
y_1 + (y_2-y_1)s &=& y_3 + t\sin{\theta} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
(x_2-x_1)s - \cos{\theta}t  &=& x_3 - x_1\\
(y_2-y_1)s - \sin{\theta}t &=& y_3  -y_1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Let's set out to eliminate $s$ from the equation. We can multiply the upper equation by $(y_2-y_1)$ and the lower equation by $-(x_2-x_1)$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)s - \cos{\theta}(y_2-y_1)t  &=& (x_3 - x_1)(y_2-y_1)\\
-(y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)s + \sin{\theta}(x_2-x_1)t &=& -(y_3  -y_1)(x_2-x_1) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
when you add the two equations together, you get
$$
 - \cos{\theta}(y_2-y_1)t + \sin{\theta}(x_2-x_1)t  = (x_3 - x_1)(y_2-y_1) - (y_3  -y_1)(x_2-x_1) 
$$
from which you can solve $t$:
$$
t = \frac{
(x_3 - x_1)(y_2-y_1) - (y_3  -y_1)(x_2-x_1) 
}{
(x_2-x_1)\sin{\theta} - (y_2-y_1) \cos{\theta}
}
$$

Comment: If I solve this, i got s= (y1-y3-(x1-x3)*tan($\theta$))/(y1-y2-(x1-x2)*tan($\theta$))

t = ((x1-x3)+(x2-x1)*s)/cos($\theta$), I have tried with test values, but i could not get the valid results.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, I made a mistake while substituting the test values. Now it worked.